# Access is denied after Robo-Copying network drive

Tags: windows, mapped-drive

Yesterday I copied a group of folders from the old file server to the new one using Robo-Copy.

Now 1 user wanted to add a file to the folder but the error gave the following message: access is denied.

I now gave the user full permissions but he still can't do anything in the folder, he can only read it.

The drive with the folder is mapped using a group policy.

Does anybody know any possible solutions? Many thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What robocopy command did you use? Can you show the [effective permissions](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/effective-permissions-tool-windows) which should tell you a lot about why they were denied access.

Comment: Can the user write to the new server in a different directory?

Comment: Nope also not possible in a different directory...

Comment: @Ghostky In that case, it sounds like the user's account does not have write permissions on the server, rather than a permission problem on individual files or directories.

Comment: Oh okay I will check that out.

Comment: @Ghostky Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: I resolved the issue, the drives were wrongly shared but I fixed it on my own thanks anyway!